# Footer div hidden behind content div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, web-deployment

I have the following webpage which works in IE7 but not in IE8;

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="inner_content">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="widget">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="widget">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="widget">
                7
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="inner_footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.inner_content, .inner_footer
{
    width:983px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
}

.content
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

.footer
{
    background:#BBBBBB;
}
```

**The problem:**

For some reason the footer div goes underneath the content div in IE8 but not in IE7.  How do I get it to look the same in IE8 as it looks in IE7?  The IE7 look is how I want it to look.

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GgpaP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contain the floated `.column`s inside `.inner_content`.

One way to do this is to add `overflow: hidden`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/GgpaP/3/

This will also make it work in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:both` to footer...

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GgpaP/2/)**

Also slight modification has been done for container.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to your content-class (in css).